# How can I snapshot a HTML DOM element in perl

Tags: html, perl, hash

Using `HTML::Parser` (or whatever else would provide the same, preferably with some suck tolerance for document sources) how can I dump the contents of a particular element node to track changes in it?

For example, given a document:

```
<body>
<div id="foo">
<div id="bar">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

What would I need to add to this code to be able to hash everything within `bar`?

```
use HTML::Parser;

sub foo {
    my $tag = shift;
    if ($tag ne "div") {
        return;
    }
    my $attrs = shift;
    my @ids = split(/ /, $attrs->{'id'});
    if (grep(/bar/, @ids)) {
        print "how do I sha256() the innerhtml here?";
    }
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
    start_h => [\&foo, 'tagname, attr'],
);

$p->parse_file('index.html');
```

Reducing to *interpreted* source would suffice.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: For such problem [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) will be suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps module `Mojo::DOM` makes solution of this task extremely easy

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::DOM;

my($page,$dom,$div_id_bar);

$page = do { local $/; <DATA> };
$dom  = Mojo::DOM->new($page);

$div_id_bar = $dom->at('div[id] > #bar');

say $div_id_bar;

exit;

__DATA__
<body>
<div id="foo">
<div id="bar">
    div block with id=bar
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Output

```
<div id="bar">
        div block with id=bar
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good approach I think. The output doesn't match your input though. There is extra white-space. The question isn't clear on whether that is part of the requirements though.

Comment: I am using [vim](https://www.vim.org/) editor with options '# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4' which represent tabulation as 4 spaces -- at copy/paste of the code it looks like 4 spaces.